# how can i get state value from another component in ngxs

Tags: angular, ngxs

common.state.ts

```
import { Action, Selector, State, StateContext } from '@ngxs/store';
import { NzMessageService } from 'ng-zorro-antd';
import { PermissionDict } from '../../model/organization-authority/setting/permission-dict.model';
import { CommonService } from '../../service/common.service';
import {GetIsSuperAdminAction} from '../action/common.action';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export interface CommonStateModel {
   superAdminState: number;
}

@State<CommonStateModel>({
    name: '_CommonState',
    defaults: {
        superAdminState: null
    }
})
@Injectable()
export class CommonState {
constructor(
    private _commonService: CommonService,
  
) {}

@Selector()
public static superAdminState(state: CommonStateModel) {
    console.log(state.superAdminState + 'A');
   //is not execute
    return state.superAdminState;
}



/**
 * @param ctx
 * @param action
 */
@Action(GetIsSuperAdminAction)
GetIsSuperAdminAction(ctx: StateContext<CommonStateModel>, action: GetIsSuperAdminAction) {
    console.log(action.superAdminState);
    const state = ctx.getState();
    ctx.setState({ ...state, superAdminState: action.superAdminState });
}
```

}

layout.component.ts:

```
onClick(){
   this._store.dispatch(new GetIsSuperAdminAction(Math.random()));
}
```

worker-dashboard.component.ts

```
superAdminState: Observable<number>;
this.superAdminState = this._store.select(CommonState.superAdminState);
```

worker-dashboard.component.html

```
{{ superAdminState | async }}
```

i can't get superAdminState state value,because superAdminState display in html value is undefined

[superAdminState value is undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1nX1.png)

[action changed the state value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wtk1a.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout component onClick method is fine and will dispatch the action you need to set the state. The thing that is missing is you will want to use the selector in this component as well. `@Select(CommonState.superAdminState) superAdminState: Observable<any>;`.

Comment: Feel free to put together a small stackblitz example if you would like.

Comment: stackblitz example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jvewmr
https://angular-ivy-jvewmr.stackblitz.io/worker-archive/worker-dashboard
thx!!

Comment: my problem is in this ruouter url:worker-archive/worker-dashboard,not in layout.component

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-14ewae?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: apologies i couldnt quite tell what the question was but this last one seems to accomplish the behavior that you want.  I think you are trying to centralize and reuse your ngxs modules in a shared module of some sort.  regarding how to make that work specifically i do not know.  unless its a lazy loaded state why would you not declare it in the app.module.ts?

Comment: thx,it's worked,i think i made a mistake where import ngxs module